# ASP.NET MVC and Angularjs vs ASP.NET MVC and Reactjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, reactjs, web-frontend

I have used AngularJs on top of my ASP.NET mvc projects. Even though both AngularJs and ASP.NET are based on mvc architecture I can see some advantages when using AngularJs on top of my ASP.NET mvc projects. The main advantage that I see in this approach is better rendering of views. If so why not use ReactJs with ASP.NET mvc since it is purely focusing on views. Why do we have to mess up with two mvc frameworks. Won't it be better to use Reactjs on top of ASP.NET mvc than using AngularJs and ASP.NET mvc combination (Note that I will always use ASP.NET mvc and I don't want to use a pure JavaScript framework). Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question is too general and without a context. It all depends on your needs. Scenario number 1 can be good in one case, while not in another and vice versa.
I guess the best way to determine this is to try to work with react and see will it suit your needs, and is it better than your previous approach.
Remember that 5+5 = 10, but you will get the same result with 2+8 :)

Comment: @Robert can you please give me a brief explanation about the scenarios when to use angularjs and reactjs with ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @DeepanCool I'm also on the same boat. I could not find any article comparing between ReactJS and AngualrJS by a veteran ASP.Net MVC developer who has used both frameworks extensively. I also think that ReactJS  might be a good choice for  ASP.Net MVC, if you do not need Route and some extras that AngularJS offers.

Comment: I also have the same question.  I've been looking for solutions to the front end programming and a good framework to learn.  I read article on article that says that Reactjs is better then Angularjs.  I also read about this new thing called bridge.net.  I would like if someone has used these frameworks with .Net and has some clear good understanding on which one will work better and be supported most in the future.  It is very confusing subject to get to the bottom of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both angular and react in projects in the past.  With angular you dirty your html markup with angular code.  With react it's all encapsulated in a component.  As I was never an expert with angular I may not have used it to the best of it's ability but to me Reactjs seems like the better framework and seems like a better fit with ASP.NET MVC.

I don't believe there is one correct tool to do the job though.  It's really whatever suits your needs and what your comfortable with.  I would suggest giving Reactjs a shot though.